# Is it possible to get the previous version of a function after altering it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, alter

I execute an alter on function in Sql Server. Is it possible to rollback this change? And what is the syntax? 
The commands aren't transactional.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are schema modifying commands transactional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133781/are-schema-modifying-commands-transactional)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change table structure in a transaction and then roll it back if there is an error?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/24883/5203)

Comment: @GSerg Although the question states "rollback" if you read it carefully you'll understand that the question has nothing to do with transactions and the `ROLLBACK` command. So, this is nod a duplicate.

Comment: @JotaBe That might be, but I'm not convinced because it may be the other way too. Please clarify in your answer that you are talking about rolling back after a commit. Rolling back from inside of a transaction certainly works for `alter function`. I also find your title edit questionable - now it does look like you understood it, but it might not be what the OP meant.

Comment: @Sara always use Version store for your objects Like SVN or TFS so that you can maintain your history for all of the objects .rollback is not a good approach for this .

Comment: Thanks  @ArunGairola ! This is a very good idea! We'll do that!

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible.

Your only hope is that you have a backup with the previous version of the function to see how it looked like before you changed it. If you don't have backups, you're out of luck.

Comment: We have a backup:) But a rollback much more quicker