# How to enable Transaction for DDL on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run multiple DDL statements inside a transaction (within SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043598/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-ddl-statements-inside-a-transaction-within-sql-s)

If I have following script:

```
BEGIN TRAN
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_2]
GO
COMMIT TRAN
```

Transcation is not working. It is still on transaction one statement.  For example, if statement 1 failed, statement 2 still is done when running the script.

How to enable Transaction for DDL?

Answer (score 2):

You're running the DDL in separate batches so if your first statement raises anything less than a connection-terminating error (hardware problem etc) the second batch will run.

Management studio treats `GO` as a batch separator and runs each batch separately.

You could use SET XACT_ABORT ON to automatically rollback your transaction in the event of an error. You can also remove the `GO` statements as ALTER TABLE statements do not need to be run in separate batches.

Comment: `XACT_ABORT` won't work without also removing `GO` as it will roll back the transaction on error then execute all the rest of the batches outside of an explicit transaction.

Comment: Correct, he'll need to follow both steps to get the behavior he wants. Most ALTER errors are not batch terminating, `XACT_ABORT` will change that.

Answer (score 0):

MagicMike is right, but I implemented an other solution I know to be efficient (even if his solution seems more elegant).
FYI, my solution with two transactions and a clean error management (the @@error feature exists on SQL Server, check the equivalent on your SQL, in Oracle it should be something like "exception when others" instead of "If (@@error=0)" ):

```
begin tran

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_1]

IF (@@Error=0)
begin
    COMMIT TRAN
end
else
begin
    rollback tran
END

begin tran    
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_2]

IF (@@Error=0)
begin
    COMMIT TRAN
end
else
begin
    rollback tran
END
```

Comment: This particular example splits each alter into its own transaction. I believe you can put your subsequent alter in the IF block to make sure no error has occurred up to that point and move the commit/rollback to a final block like is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable or enable the DDL command

Just do the following
you can use

```
Begin Try
.......
End Try
Begin Catch
.......
End Try
```

in your terms of example 
you can do this way

```
begin try

ALTER TABLE [dbo].temp CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_1]
--GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].temp CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_2]
--GO

end try

begin catch
    print 'Error in the Try Block'
end catch
```