# Spring Programmatic Transaction Management doesn't rollback when an exception is thrown

Tags: spring, transactions

Because I have a lot of data sources very dynamically, I'd like to find a way to manage spring transation programmatically, create data sources programmatically. 
In the code below, I will create table t1 twice designedly to make an exception thrown, transation will be rollback. But when I run the code, table "t1" will be created, and "t1name" will be inserted into column "name". 
Why rollback doesn't work in my case?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc", "root", "root");

    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource); 
    TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = null;

    try {       
        sql = "create table t1 (`name` varchar(30))";
        PreparedStatementCreatorFactory statementCreatorFactory = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sql);
        PreparedStatementCreator creator = statementCreatorFactory.newPreparedStatementCreator(new Object[] {});
        jdbc.update(creator);       

        sql = "INSERT INTO `t1` (`name`) VALUES ('t1name')";    
        statementCreatorFactory = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sql);
        statementCreatorFactory.setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);
        creator = statementCreatorFactory.newPreparedStatementCreator(new Object[] {});
        GeneratedKeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbc.update(creator, keyHolder);

        sql = "create table t1 (`name` varchar(30))";       // table exists already, will cause rollback. 
        statementCreatorFactory = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sql);
        creator = statementCreatorFactory.newPreparedStatementCreator(new Object[] {});
        jdbc.update(creator);                   

        transactionManager.commit(status);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        transactionManager.rollback(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like this could be related: [Is it possible to run multiple DDL statements inside a transaction (within SQL Server)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1043598/217324)

Comment: Thanks Nathan, will check into that.

Comment: Nathan, you are right. I changed "create table" into "insert", it works. My database is mysql. Thank you so much.